# Vue/Apollo useQuery with variables doesn't cache requests

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, apollo, quasar-framework

I'm using `Quasar` with `Apollo` and the following component `ProductsListPage.vue` works as expected when `route.params.id` changes:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <h2>CategoryID: {{ this.routeId }} </h2>

    <q-item v-for="Product in Products" :key="Product.id">

      <q-item-section class="my-box cursor-pointer q-hoverable">
        <q-item-label>
          {{ Product.Products_id.name }}
        </q-item-label>
        <q-item-label caption>ID: {{ Product.Products_id.id }}</q-item-label>
      </q-item-section>

    </q-item>

  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { useQuery, useLazyQuery, useResult } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ProductDetailPage',
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    const routeId = ref(route.params.id);

    const { result: Products, refetch } = useQuery(
      gql`
        query GetProducts($categoriesByIdId: ID!) {
          Categories_by_id(id: $categoriesByIdId) {
            Products {
              Products_id {
                id
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      {
        categoriesByIdId: routeId.value,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
        //keyFields: ['Categories_by_id.id', ['Products', 'Products_id.id']],
      }
    );

    const ProductsData = useResult(Products, [], (data) => data.Categories_by_id.Products);

    watch(
      () => route.params.id,
      (newValue, oldValue) => {
        routeId.value = newValue;
        refetch({ categoriesByIdId: newValue });
      },
    );

    return {
      routeId,
      Products: ProductsData,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

However it's making a request every time the route changes despite `fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'`. My suspicion is that `refetch` forces request and ignores the policy.

The reason I'm using it though, is because without it, it's not reactive to changes of `route.params.id` (which is passed to `useQuery` as variable). So the `watch()` is needed to call the query again.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this with both reactivity and cache working?

Also the code above works only when passing a variable directly as `{categoriesByIdId:routeId.value}`. If I use the recommended `{variables: {categoriesByIdId:routeId.value} }` it doesn't work. Why?